# Magento 2 multiple websites but same product catalog

Tags: magento2, admin, multistore

In Magento 2, it's possible to create **multiple websites** and share the same **product catalog** once the product is posted? (Not by doing manually) So far I'm able to do it with **multi-stores** and different domains but not with multiple websites. Multiple websites do share the same root category but the products posted on website A doesn't show in website B.

Products must keep same description, photos, price, stock, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible in both Magento 1 and Magento 2. The only thing you need to do is assign each product to both of your websites. You can do this individually or in bulk in the admin panel.

Comment: where in the admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

Please assign your products for multi websites from Admin->Catalog->Select a Product->Product in Websites->select your website https://prnt.sc/naxybb. Also, You can assign website by using update attributes from grid https://prnt.sc/naxylf. And select the websites and assign them.

THanks